# Question about task continuation

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library

task1:

```
public Task SendMail(string email)
 {
  ...
 }
```

task2:

```
public Task<int> SaveToDB(User user)
 {
  ...
 }
```

What I need to do:

1. when task1 fail, should return a "send failure" infomation;
2. when task1 success, task2 begin.
3. when task2 fail, should return a "save failure" infomation.
4. when task2 success, should return a "save success" infomation.

Please help me find a solution:

```
public Task<string> SendAndSave(User user){
var task1 = SendMail(user.Email);
var task1Failed = task1.ContinueWith(t =>   
{
     var e = task1.Exception;
     return "Send Failed";
}, 
TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted | 
TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously);

var task2 = task1.ContinueWith(t =>
{
    var save = SaveToDB(user);
    try
    {
        int result = save.Result;
        return "Save Succeeded"; 
      }
     catch(AggregateException ae)
     {
          return "Save Failed";
      }
      },
      TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnFaulted); 

 return Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAny(new[] {task1Failed, task2}, t => t.Result);
 }
```

When I run it I receive an error.

I invoked it as:

`var result = SendAndSave(user).Result;`

the error occured at:

```
public Task<string> SendAndSave(User user)
{
      ...
      return Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAny(new[] {task1Failed, task2}, t => t.Result);   //Here: A task was cancelled
 }
```

After debugging it , I have two questions:

- Q1: after task1, task1Failed, task2 are created, the value of each
  CreationOption property is "none" although its Status is
  "WaitingForActivation". It seems all the continuation options are
  invalid.
- Q2: For the task of Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAny(new[] {task1Failed,
  task2}, t => t.Result), let's name it "factoryTask", the
  ContinueWhenAny seems invalid. After put a breakpoint in the internal
  of each of task1Failed, task2 and factoryTask, I can see occasionally
  the breakpoint in the factoryTask was hitted firstly, though it
  should be hitted after either task1Failed or task2 had completed.

Anybody can help ? Thanks.

Comment: maybe you can start by telling us, what the error was exactly?

Answer (score 1):

Although I don't fully understand your questions, I understand the issue here, basically you will always have either task1Failed or task2 completes but not both, and the other one will be cancelled!
So in WaitOnAny call, if it finds one of the tasks is already cancelled, it will crash, and this really depends on the order of the tasks parameter, so in your example above you pass task1failed first, so if this task completeted ContinueWhenAny will work fine because the first task it checks is already completed so it doesn't check the other one, but if task1Failed didn't run so it is in a cancelled state, ContinueWhenAny will throw!

To avoid this, you need to use TaskCompletetionSource instead, and the task which runs, will set the value, then at the end you return tcs.Task.Result

```
public Task<string> SendAndSave(User user){
var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();
var task1 = SendMail(user.Email);
var task1Failed = task1.ContinueWith(t =>   
{
     var e = task1.Exception;
     tcs.TrySetResult("Send Failed");
}, 
TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted | 
TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously);

var task2 = task1.ContinueWith(t =>
{
    var save = SaveToDB(user);
    try
    {
        int result = save.Result;
        tcs.TrySetResult("Save Succeeded"); 
    }
    catch(AggregateException ae)
    {
       tcs.TrySetResult("Save Failed"); 
    }
},TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnFaulted); 

 return tcs.Task.Result;
}
```

Comment: props to you spending the time to answer this question